# Background process in node

Tags: node.js, express, child-process, mern

I am new to the whole javascript stack .I have been trying to learn by building a small application based on React-Express-Mongo. My application basically saves some config settings to mongo . And based on these settings the app periodically tries to fetch some values by querying and elasticsearch index. 
So far i have the part to save the config settings done.

What I need to do now ,is to extract these setting from my mongo DB and schedule a job which keeps runnning periodically (the period is one of the settings) to poll my elastic index.The thing that i cannot wrap my head around ,is how do I create this scheduled job. All i have been using till now is the Express router to interact with my UI and DB.

I did some research ,would spawning a child process be the ideal way to go ahead with this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go take a look to [node-corn.](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron) Cron is a popular task scheduler on UNIX and node-cron is its implementation in node.

Basic usage - taken from the doc

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
    console.log('You will see this message every second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

Comment: Thanks this should do the trick, ill look up on the documentation .